# организация цикла в алгоритме Флойда

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы

У меня вопрос по поводу организации цикла в алгоритме Флойда , какие условия нужно предусмотреть для графа n*n , если не сложно : обьясните для чего нужна дополнительная матрица в методе , не совсем понятно , вот мой код (-1 означает что дороги из одного узла в другой напрямую нету , граф ориентированный):

```
void Floyd_Algorithm(int** A, int size)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                
                if (A[i][k] > -1 && A[k][j] > -1)
                {
                    A[i][j] = min(A[i][j], A[i][k] + A[k][j]);
                }
                
            }
        }
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что ваш код изменяет значения матрицы, и в результате использует для вычисления не исходные значения, а уже измененные - и тем самым получает неверные значения...

Покажу на более простом примере - например, для массива надо вычислить новый массив, в котором на каждом месте стоит сумма этого элемента и предшествующего. Например, для

```
1   2   3   1   4   6   ...
```

надо получить

```
1   3   5   4   5   10 ...
```

А теперь представьте, что вы записываете результаты **в тот же массив**

```
1   3
```

а теперь не 5, а уже 6, потому что теперь второй элемент уже не 2, а 3...

```
1   3   6
```

а следующий элемент не 4 (1+3), а уже 1+6 = 7...

Так понятно, почему нужна дополнительная матрица?

Comment: Да , спасибо , до меня дошло

Comment: В данном конкретном случае дополнительная матрица не нужна